# Cannot find module '@firebase/functions-types' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

I upgraded from firebase 6 to 9 and angular-fire to 7.2 (with angular 13), but now this error appears (7.4 with angular 14 is the same problem):

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/functions/functions.d.ts: Cannot find module '@firebase/functions-types' or its corresponding type declarations.

import { HttpsCallableOptions } from '@firebase/functions-types';
```

I tried to delete the node_modules folder and reinstalled with `npm i` . But nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Battled with this for some time, and tried many things but I *think* my problem was conflicting versions of dependencies in `package-lock.json`. What finally seemed to solve it for me (after updating to angular v14) was:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case run npm i @firebase/functions-types

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).